# What's the advantage of nested class over a class attribute?

Tags: django

Django nests the Meta class inside to the plural in `models.py`:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ....
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
```

'entries' overrides 'entrys'.

I guess this could be done easily without employing a `class` if I design Django.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
# set verbose_name_plural as a class attribute
```

What's the advantage of nested class over a class attribute?

Comment: *I guess this could be done easily without employing a `class` if I design Django.* I guess you overestimate your software developing skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is roughly that all attributes directly on the class that inherits `models.Model` should correspond to a column/field in the database table.

`class Meta` is then the place where you put all other non-column/field related configuration such as `verbose_name_plural` or `label`.

Docs explaining it in detail [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options)